# IDLE call project

Tags: python, python-idle

Is there a way of running a project through IDLE from another script. The code below opens the project `File.py` in the idle interface to be edited. Is there a way of doing this running the program in doing so.

```
import os
os.system (path + '\\idlelib\\idle.bat File.py')
```

This code opens a python shell but doesn't take an argument to run my project.

```
import idlelib.pyshell
idlelib.pyshell.main ()
```

Simply, an idle shell window should open running my `File.py` project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `-r` parameter (before the script name) when launching IDLE via your `os.system()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it has nothing to do with the fact that you are in Idle.  Just run it the way you would in the Bash terminal.

```
import os
os.system ('python File.py')
```

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to call a project through IDLE, not just run it generally.